# Connect old USB webcam to USB Host Shield 2.0 Arduino Uno / Mega

Tags: usb, camera

Does anybody know how to interface an old USB webcam with the USB Host Shield 2.0 connected to an Arduino (Uno or Mega 2560 or other models - excluding Yun).

I've got the USB Host Shield set up properly and I can run all the examples.

My goal is to make the arduino force the webcam to take a picture (the webcam itself has a button for taking pictures) every second and save it to the SD card of the ethernet shield.

I know how to read and write data to the SD card of the ethernet shield. That's not the problem.

The problem is making the Arduino talk to the USB webcam.
Can anybody please share a basic .ino file with me so I can see what magic they used to do the trick?

I tried the Arduino PTP Camera Control library by felis over at:
https://github.com/felis/Arduino_Camera_Control

But I'm having lots of trouble getting the included examples to work properly with my old USB webcam. I always get the 'can't read data' error in the serial monitor...

Thanks for any help!

Comment: This will not be practical.  USB Webcams are not PTP devices - that is for already recorded images.  Don't use an Arduino for this project, use something more like a Raspberry Pi, though preferably without the delicate SD card dependency - possibly even the Linux (not Arduino) side of that Yun you want to avoid, or perhaps a hackable router/NAS box which is what that is a repackaged and repurposed variation of.  Cheapest and simplest of all of course would be to just get a cheap still camera that records to an SD card.

Comment: Most simple webcams use USB video device class UVC protocol. Ptp is supported on some webcams but UVC is much more common.

Comment: Thanks for the comments guys. Please keep the good ideas coming. So what you're telling me is that I should look into the library called libuvc https://github.com/ktossell/libuvc ? Could this library actually work with the Arduino Uno / Mega and the Arduino IDE ? Or do you know of another UVC library that's compatible with Arduino ? I couldn't find anything UVC related in the Arduino Library Manager.

Comment: @Passerby If this is an old webcam, it may not use the UVC protocol.

Comment: Re-read the first comment: **an Arduino is not remotely suitable to this task**.

Comment: "how to interface an old USB webcam" -  maybe you just need to start looking for actual specifications for this "an old USB webcam", what it is adhered to? Why do you think that some arbitrary "library" is supposed to work with "an old webcam"? Did you try your "an old webcam" under regular Windows or Linux environment? Does it work? What kind of driver does it use?

Comment: In case it matters: I'm using an old intel cs330 webcam. This is what it looks like:
https://www.ebay.com/p/Intel-CS330-Web-Cam/66777500

When plugging in this webcam in Ubuntu it is recognized by Cheese so I'm guessing it utilizes either the PTP or the UVC protocol or similar.